# how to add Parcelable Object into Parcelable Object

Tags: parcelable

I must deliver an Object value to other Activity, so I found the way to using Parcelable Object. but this is the problem

the outer ParcelableOjbect (I'll call this "1") has inner ParcelableOjbect variable(I'll call this "2").
so what I have to do is add innerParcelableObject into a outerParcelableObject.

the "2" which is I'll add is already setted up to Parcelable class

but the error occured line says this

```
writeParcelable(Parcelable, int) in Parcel cannot be applied
to             (State)
```

This is the (1)

```
ublic class Progress implements Parcelable {
    String time;
    String location;
    State status;                  // <<<----- this is (2)
    String description;

    public Progress(){}
    public Progress(String time, String location, State status, String description) {
        this.time = time;
        this.location = location;
        this.status = status;
        this.description = description;
    }
    protected Progress(Parcel in){
        in.writeString(time);
        in.writeString(location);
        in.writeParcelable(status);   // <<--  the error occured here
        in.writeString(description);
    }

    public static final Creator<Progress> CREATOR = new Creator<Progress>() {
        @Override
        public Progress createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Progress(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Progress[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Progress[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }

    // ... getters and setters

}
```

This is the (2)

```
public class State implements Parcelable {

    String id;
    String text;

    public State(String id, String text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.text = text;
    }
    protected State(Parcel in) {
        in.writeString(id);
        in.writeString(text);
    }

    public static final Creator<State> CREATOR = new Creator<State>() {
        @Override
        public State createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new State(in);
        }

        @Override
        public State[] newArray(int size) {
            return new State[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

    }

    // ... getters and setters
}
```

Is anything missing on this?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself

The following link says the way to add ParcelableObject into ParcelableObject.
thanks to this link https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable

This is content the method named "writeToParcel"

```
        out.writeString(title);
        out.writeParcelable(from, flags);
```

as you can see, when you add Parcelable Object, you have to pass "flags" for argument.

Then, when you read from Parcel

```
        title= in.readString();
        from = in.readParcelable(Person.class.getClassLoader());
```

You can read from parcel to use this way. And attention! You must matching their index that you wrote.

I hope this solution will help others